# Python/Numpy/Scipy, Solving non-linear least squares, with grouped covariates?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

Basically, I'm trying to make this function happen:

[image]

Where i'm solving for the beta.  gamma, alpha, and x are all from the data.

Originally, I just used the summary statistic mean(xi/gamma_i), which meant that everything in that summation could be pre-calculated, and then i would just present a simple np array to the non-linear optimizer... but now there's no way to pre-calculate the summary statistic, as it's not immediately clear how beta will affect f when f is changing in response to alpha_i.  Thus, I'm not sure how to go about presenting that array.  is it possible to embed those covariates as lists (numpy Objects) to still present a numpy array, and then unpack the list within the residual function?  Am i going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I see here one equation and one unknown variable. Why do you talk about least-squares minimization but not about root finding?

Comment: That's the formula for the predicted value of x_0... The formula for the residual would be x_0 - the above, then i'd be doing least squares minimization on the residual formula applied across a dataset (where there are many x_0's).

Short answer:  this is a statistics problem, not an algebra problem.

Comment: Ok. So you really have additional index, say j at the left side of your equation. What about variables in the right side? Beta is a scalar, but other are vectors or matrices?